# How to restart Ubuntu box (14/15) on power loss, after after soft shutdown via 'apcupsd'?

Tags: boot, server, power-management, shutdown, ups

Hello Ubuntu community -

I've searched the forums, and scoured the internet, without resolution to this issue.  I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 (formerly 14) on an Intel NUC (5i), connected to a Back-UPS 550 via USB cable, and can confirm the following:

- apcupsd is installed and working
- BIOS has been set to "Always Resume" in the Power Loss setting
- Basic configuration file exists and appears correct
- Restart-on-power functionality works correctly when *not* using the UPS -- if I pull the plug on the NUC and then reconnect, the unit powers on.

Shutdown appears to be working correctly in my tests when I pull the plug on the UPS, unfortunately the unit stays off when power is restored.

It's as if the apcupsd shutdown behavior is causing a normal shutdown in Ubuntu, instead of indicating to the hardware that an emergency shutdown took place -- when power is restored to the UPS, the unit doesn't immediately power-on like it does when not using the ups.

What am I missing here?  I've covered a lot of ground online, including:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/apcupsd

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance,

-j

Comment: Complete shot in the dark here, but if it's possible to make the machine restart instead of shut down, wouldn't that work? The UPS would be almost dead, so the computer would shut down and power back on, only to be force shut down before the OS can boot, meaning the BIOS would power back on when power is restored, since it had what it thinks to be a power disconnect.

Comment: This is essentially the kind of workaround I'm trying to avoid... rebooting and then having the server terminate cold during a boot sequence is a study in how to abuse your server IMHO

Comment: Not really. It is a bit dirty, but since the OS hasn't yet booted, there isn't much chance of corruption.